# Dark images in Chrome

Tags: images, google-chrome

Couple of days ago the images in Chrome (some photos and some other images) became suddenly much darker than they should be.

The same images opened in i.e. Firefox are fine. What could be the problem?

Please help me, this drives me crazy. Chrome version is 22.0.1229.79 m, OS Windows XP SP3.

This is screenshot example, how different it looks like in both browsers:

[image]

[This](http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=475256859174015&set=a.194777810555256.46577.192296894136681&type=1&theater) is the url for the image in question..

---

I reinstalled Chrome several times, also reinstalled graphic card (Radeon X550) drivers. It did not help. Everything was fine all the time only from couple of days ago the images are now darker in Chrome. Probably bug in Chrome (they issued new version on Sept. 27).

I will wait for the new Chrome update if it will help. Otherwise - is it possible that I inadvertently changed some Windows setting which is causing it??

Is there some setting in Windows to impact images displaying?

Comment: You need 10 reputation to post images or more than two links in a question or answer.  Note that a user with sufficient reputation may edit a question or answer written by a low-reputation user to add the image or additional links.  10 points can be earned just by gaining one upvote on an answer or two upvotes on a question.  See http://superuser.com/privileges/new-user to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

When you uninstall chrome it is not removed completely.

- Uninstall Chrome.
- Go to the folder `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\`
- backup folder "User Data"
- Delete the entire contents of the folder `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\`
- Restart your computer
- Reinstall Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Google enabled support for ICC profiles in images by default: http://www.chromestory.com/2012/09/google-chrome-now-supports-icc-v2-profiles/

It's a feature, not a bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=143

Unfortunately, I am not aware about disabling this function... maybe you have misconfigured you monitor icc profile?